# How to get variable values from struck in swift

Tags: swift

I have the swift code and I am able to set variable inside my struct. My issues is that I can't get var values out of the struct. I get the following error

```
Missing arguments for parameters 'source', 'sourcePackets' in call
Insert 'source: <#Any#>, sourcePackets: <#Any#>'
```

```
 struct midiMessage{
    var source: Any;
    var sourcePackets: Any;
    
  }

  func one(){
      let midiData = midiMessage(source: "abc", sourcePackets: "def")
  }

   func two(){
      let a = midiMessage();
      print(a.source)
  }
```

Comment: How do you call func two? You create a new midiMessage with no parameters.

Comment: Please read this:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Answer (score 0):

You declare a `struct`:

```
struct midiMessage{
    var source: Any;
    var sourcePackets: Any;    
}
```

The first thing that strikes me as odd is that your type name begins with a lower case letter.  It should probably be `MidiMessage` or `MIDIMessage`.  But that is a naming convention so you can name it that way - it just looks odd.

The second thing that strikes me as odd, is that your fields have the type `Any`.  Swift's type system is part of its safety and performance.  The `Any` type is a catch-all type that sometimes shows up as the type system tries to figure out what something might be - but it's certainly not something that I would expect anyone to use intentionally except under very odd circumstances.  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but you probably don't want to use the `Any` type.

When you declared your struct, you gave it two fields.  Any time you want to instantiate that struct - when you want to build one - you have to tell the system what value to put in those two fields.

In func 2 you try to create a `midiManager` and assign it to the variable `a`.  But you don't tell the system what value to store in the two fields.  In fact you don't provide any parameters to the construction call at all:

```
  func two() {
      let a = midiMessage();
      print(a.source)
  }
```

The error says "You told me that a `midiManager` has a `source` field, and a `sourcePackets` field.  But here you are tying to create one with `midiManager()` you don't tell me what to put in those fields.

It expects you to provide values.